# CoreData can't fulfill a fault during save operation from background MOC

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am using two MOCs, one for the main thread, and another MOC on a background thread.
On the main thread I have a UITableView working with an FRC (NSFetchedResultsController).

Once in a while I run a massive save operation, that deletes all objects and builds a few hundreds of new objects... At this point I want to UITableView in the main thread to refresh its data (using the FRC obviously). Therefore the main MOC registers to the NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification notification (received from the background MOC) and runs mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification at that stage to make sure the UITableView updates accordingly.

This all works fine until I try to scroll the UITableView during the save operation. When I try to scroll the view a "coredata could not fulfill a fault" exception is raised. This is the result of the FRC still holding objects that were already deleted (while the save operation still runs, before mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification from NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification notification is received on main MOC). 
This is some sort of a "race condition" between the save operation and the update of the UITableView after mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification is received.

What is the right approach to work with those two MOCs and taking care of the FRC so it will be able to cope with this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

As per [apples doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdTroubleshooting.html):

> Fault cannot be fulfilled Problem: You see the error message, "Core
>   Data could not fulfill a fault".
>
> Cause: The corresponding object's underlying data has been deleted
>   from the persistent store.
>
> Remedy: You should discard this object.
>
> This problem can occur in at least two situations:
>
> First:
>
> Start with a strong reference to a managed object. Delete the managed
>   object via the managed object context. Save changes on the object
>   context. At this point, the deleted object has been turned into a
>   fault. It isn’t destroyed because doing so would violate the rules of
>   memory management.
>
> Try to retrieve an attribute or relationship from the previously
>   retained reference. Core Data will try to fault the faulted managed
>   object but will fail to do so because the object has been deleted from
>   the store. That is, there is no longer an object with the same global
>   ID in the store.
>
> Second:
>
> Delete an object from a managed object context. Fail to break all
>   relationships from other objects to that object. Save changes.

Comment: Thanks. I've read this post... What is the best way considering the architecture and scenario I described to "discard this object"?